# Texture Baking Symmetrical Model Gives Asymmetrical Result

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting, texture-baking, baking

I've been trying to bake the procedural shadows made by this shader, down to a single BaseColor texture, and with success, but there is a weird problem with asymmetrical baking, in the viewport it is okay, but in the bake there is too much shadow in some places:
[image: shader]

Viewport :

[image: Viewport]

Baked Texture :
[image: Baked Texture]

As you can see the left eye has more shadow than the right one, any ideas why this is happening and maybe how to solve it?

Thanks in advance,
Olivier

Comment: Are you using non-directional (no sun) lights?

Comment: Yes, I use the light coming from the background as a light source. There are no other lights in the scene.

Comment: which map are you baking? This setup should go into emit

Comment: I think it was on Combined Render pass and I was trying to bake it as a BaseColor / Diffuse map. Anyhow, I solved the problem with Photoshop, but still wondering why it went wrong in the 1st place!

Comment: Have you enabled only this object for render? For example, is there an eyeball that is hidden but will get rendered?

Comment: I dont know how you guessed it but you are absolutely right! This was the solution, thanks a lot for your insight :D!

Comment: glad you found it, just a bit of smartypantsery: setting it to emit should solve that problem as well and bake much faster. (in your case). However you need to set the AO node to only local.